# dependency in cocoa touch framework using cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am planning to write a cocoa touch framework, is it possible to add other frameworks  dependency using cocopods ?.I am plannig to release it through cocoapods, I want to add AFNetworking in my cocoa touch framework.

Comment: You can, you also can also make development pod and code in there if you plan to release it as source

Comment: you can add AFNetworking as vendored_framework in pod.spec file of your custom pod

 s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'AFNetworking.framework'

Comment: thanks for the answer

Comment: Please provide an answer using the site's Q&A functionality so this question can be closed.

Comment: @ManojKarki Is that answer solved your problem?

Comment: @Serkan yes it solved my problem